# How to change value of element in object array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

this is my html list-

```
<ul id="board"> 
    <li class="card" id="card1a">1</div>
    <li class="card" id="card1b" >2</div>
    <li class="card" id="card2a" >3</div>
    <li class="card" id="card2b" >4</div>
</ul>
```

I made to an array in javaScript:

```
var cards=document.getElementsByClassName("card");
```

Than I tried to replace elements inside the array-

```
var temporaryValue = cards[0];
cards[0] = cards[2];
cards[2] = temporaryValue;
```

It didn't work: cards[0] and card[2] stayed in the same values. I don't know why.
Please help!

Comment: Are you trying to change the values in html list (`ul` and `li`) our just inside the `cards` variable?

Comment: You're just changing element references around, not the actual `<li>` elements they're pointing to. If you want to "change" the HTML, you need to remove a `<li>`, then insert it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an array. It returns a live HTMLCollection -- an *array-like* object (ie: an object that presents a similar API) that contains matching elements in document order. The contents reflect the actual state of the document, you can't just swap stuff around in it.

If you want to swap the elements themselves, you can use the DOM to do it. (As you do that, the changes will propagate to your list as well.) If you just want to have an array you can swap entries around in, then copy the list to an array of your own.

Comment: Thanks, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to change the `textContent`

This is how you do it

```
cards[0].textContent = cards[2].textContent
```

```js
var cards=document.getElementsByClassName("card");

cards[0].textContent = cards[2].textContent
```

```html
<ul id="board"> 
    <li class="card" id="card1a">1</li>
    <li class="card" id="card1b" >2</li>
    <li class="card" id="card2a" >3</li>
    <li class="card" id="card2b" >4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

with the .getElementsByClassName("card"); you just get the reference of the html element and not the value directly, **you can use innerText to replace** and to get the text inside the element.

```
var temporaryValue = cards[0].innerText;
cards[0].innerText = cards[2].innerText;
cards[2.innerText = temporaryValue;
```

Hope it helps!